# Facebook OAuthException when calling taggable_friends using Social Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, social-networking

I am using social framework to fetch taggable_friends of a user. When I call api for the first time using  below the url it is working fine.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/taggable_friends", userId];
```

and the response was in the format

```
{
  "data": [
     ... Endpoint data is here
  ],
   paging =     {
    cursors =         {
        after = QWFKQ0lLNDF0S05vZAXBCSWQxNDM1MTFpbFBhZAXlYV2F5X2Uxb1BpWDVTUU82LUFYamZAYWUpfQTRFWXplSkRzRU9BYXNUSWVtS2ZAfT21tdlNycXFCWXNPcUxoR01SNkd3UXZAYMldYV1RuTW9qcGcZD;
        before = QWFJS2E3TGJDelFlNi04bldxRG4zcnVUeXVyY2l0VGVVTk84U1VWdV9ZAUFJrb08zTF90d3ZArXzJsb2tabFZA6X2lmNUVQQXFsUGh6NVJrbzFGRm9teldWZATdqak5CUm9GM0VHTmVrZAkRSZAFAzZAlEZD;
    };
    next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/996970000322616/taggable_friends?access_token=CAAXvxRj0GjEBAFxaMmhzW4qotmQ1uZBOuRWlYp1JFswoupPtUllRKihgoXLu0LqVyf6hoqumHB9PVuIS9VEKp6QLZCh9SizDV1xteqsVR7RtjzxifpJZCdXzTamdZCwVasmMIBGidUsuyOFCL8SAjBqLwlK57q1hwtpYJkb9WuXAY2oO9ZCujmuZCSMeuFeSvsLOprARaufbVfwS3z7H4KWi9KqQG6BZBYTSWtHHGAJ1gZDZD&limit=25&after=QWFKQ0lLNDF0S05vZAXBCSWQxNDM1MTFpbFBhZAXlYV2F5X2Uxb1BpWDVTUU82LUFYamZAYWUpfQTRFWXplSkRzRU9BYXNUSWVtS2ZAfT21tdlNycXFCWXNPcUxoR01SNkd3UXZAYMldYV1RuTW9qcGcZD";
};

}
```

Since the response is paginated i made a second request to fetch the friends(recursive call) in the second page using url in 'next'. But When I called the api, i got the oAuthException as below

```
error =     {
    code = 1;
    message = "An unknown error has occurred.";
    type = OAuthException;
};
```

When I loaded the above 'next' url in the browser, it was loading the correct data.

I used SLRequest(Social Framework) to fetch the response from the Facebook

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl];
    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                      URL:url
                                               parameters:nil];
    request.account = facebookAccount;
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                           options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                             error:nil];
```

Also I set the following permissions on the `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` method

```
    NSDictionary *options = @{ ACFacebookAppIdKey: FB_APP_ID ,
                               ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"basic_info",@"user_friends"]};
```

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: Are you seeing the same behavior when running the queries in the Graph API Explorer?

Comment: No..In grapha API explorer it is working fine. Also when i load the get url in the browser it is working fine.

Comment: the same issue. But it worked fine. After one day - just not wokring